# Laravel unittest migrate vendor package with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I've added to the sentry package this migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddFieldsUsers extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() 
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            /* TODO unittest */
            $table->string('fullname');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() 
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->dropColumn(array('fullname', 'username'));
        });
    }

}
```

so when I go to testing I need just a users table in my SQlite.
How to add this

> php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry

in my set up

```
public function setUpDb()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate');
    }
```

### ENDS UP

silly me ^^

```
public function setUpDb()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate', array('--package'=>'cartalyst/sentry'));
        Artisan::call('migrate');
    }
```